# Test consistency over different runs/processes with pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I would like to write a test using pytest which fails when a function has a different outcome on different runs. An easy example would be `hash("abc")`

On the terminal:

```
$> python -c 'print(hash("abc"))'
7757446167780988571
$> python -c 'print(hash("abc"))'
-1754122997235049390
```

However in one run we have of course:

```
>>> hash("abc")
-2233283646379253139
>>> hash("abc")
-2233283646379253139
```

How can I write a test (using pytest) that tests the consistency of the outcome of a function using different processes/runs such that it would fail for `hash("abc")`?

Background is that I'm implementing a DB access function which compares the binary strings of pickled/dilled dictionaries. However these strings will vary from run to run for the same dictionary.
I want to test for consistency because the function should not add to the DB if the dict is already in it..

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! However, for the actual problem it's not really feasible. Because the function I'll be calling needs quite a number of fixtures. I'll check if I find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon Dov Benyomin Sohacheskis answer, I ended up with the following solution to the more elaborate problem of testing the consistency of a function with test fixtures and all..

I'll post it here because it might be helpful to others as well.
I assume that `fixture` holds the `args` and `kwargs` to the function to be tested.

```
import tempfile
import dill
import functools
import subprocess

def test_consistency_of_f(fixture):

    args, kwargs = fixture

    f = functools.partial(function_to_be_tested, *args, **kwargs)

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td:
        fn = os.path.join(td, 'test.dill')
        with open(fn, 'wb') as fi:
            dill.dump(f, fi)
        cmd = """import dill
with open('{}', 'rb') as fi:
    f=dill.load(fi)
print(f())
""".format(fn)
        cmd = ['python', '-c', cmd]
        s1 = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
        s2 = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
        if not s1 == s2:
            print(1, s1)
            print(2, s2)
        assert s1 == s2
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a hacked solution but you can use processes to achieve your goal.

```
import subprocess

def test_hash():
    # Create the command
    cmd = ['python', '-c', 'print(hash("abc"), end="")']

    # Run a sub-process
    other_hash = subprocess.check_output(cmd)

    assert hash('abc') != int(other_hash)
```